Bizarre movie where a mother is on drugs, abandons her son and he becomes a Christian
The mother leaves her son and after some time she wants to see him again. She leaves him again and again and always wants him to take her back. She's on drugs, the boy becomes a Christian, and in one scene he dresses like a girl and has sex with his mother's boyfriend. It's really bizarre.
Crows appear there from time to time, and the mother and the son say "the fire is coming" or something like that.
It is probably a French film, and I remember that the actress that portrays the mother is the same person that directs the movie or produces it. 
Added details:

The movie is in color.
I watched it on DVD between 2006 and 2015.


Hi! Do you remember the approximate year\decade of release? When did you see it? Was it on TV\DVD\in a theater? Was it in color?

Sounds like The Heart Is Deceitful Above All Things from 2004 that Asia Argento wrote, directed and starred in as the mother.

The dysfunctional twenty-three-year-old Sarah takes her six-year-old natural son Jeremiah from the home of his beloved foster parents with the support of the social service to live with her. Along the years, the boy shares her insane and low lifestyle and is introduced to booze and drugs and mentally, physically and sexually abused by Sarah, her lovers and her religiously fanatic family.

The boy dreams of red crows; his mother dresses him up like a girl and he seduces her boyfriend, played by Marilyn Manson(!). Jeremy Renner, Winona Ryder and Peter Fonda also appear. Trailer:



